how to get the file extension of a file with just the file path/name and not specifiying the extension
Lets say you have some path Python\Project\some_image but you don't know the file extensions, since it's a photo that could be any type (.png, .jpg, etc.)
So, how would you get the file extension with just the path? Is that even possible?
I've tried using the pathlib module, but without actually giving a file extension when creating a Path object, it doesn't give a suffix. You can't open a file without a file extension, either.

You would need to do a directory search using a wildcard (*) in place of the extension. That should give you a list of all the files in that directory.

glob.glob('Python/Project/some_image.*')

PIL
